# Launch Android app with params

Tags: android, appium

In iOS you can use 'processArguments' capability and when you open the app the arguments are available on AppDelegate.

Is there a similar method for Android?

There's the 'optionalIntentArguments' capability that enables to add keys to the intent and use them in the MainActivity - but what if I want that data available in the 'Application' class that executes earlier?

Comment: this is what `Intent`'s "extras" are for

Comment: yes, but Intents only get in play when the activity is launched. I need the data before the activity is launch (in the 'Application' class) therefore Intent extra's is not suitable

Comment: you cannot get the data in the `Application` class: it doesn't work that way

Comment: so there's no other alternative similar to process arguments in iOS? (obviously it's not with the intent extra but my question if there's an alternative)

Comment: honestly i have no idea what do you need that `Application` class for...

Comment: in Android you extend Application class when you need custom code to run in the entry point of the app (for instance - you do it in react native app). I need to get some environment/process arguments in that scope

Comment: this is overuse, `Application` docs say: *"Note: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way."*

Answer (score -1):

You can get the data from Intent and then store it in SharedPreference and keep using it till you want.

Comment: see my comment above - not able to use intents for this scenraio